# Unable to import a powershell module from a script

Tags: powershell, module

I have a strange problem I have created a module and placed it in the **“C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules”** directory .

I can open powershell and import my module fine but it does not work when I do the following.

I have batch file that calls the powershell script using the following command 
**START /min /wait powershell "C:\test.ps1" "%1"**

The script starts but it is unable to import module.

I placed this command “Get-Module -ListAvailable | Out-File c:\module.txt” in the test.ps1.

When I review the module.txt file I see it does not list my module there.

It seems that for some reason when I call the script this way it can’t access the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module has to be either a `.psm1` file or a `.psd1` manifest file (or a dll).  A `.ps1` doesn't qualify as a module, it is "just" a script.

Comment: I have one file called test.psm1 in a directory called test

Comment: Is this a 64-bit system?  If so, can you check to see if the PowerShell instance created by the batch file is a 64-bit or a 32-bit PowerShell?  Stick in `[intptr]::size > c:\test.log` in your test.ps1 file.

Comment: It is a 64bit system and the instance is 32 bit , does that make a difference , do I need to change any thing ?

Comment: any idea why cmd is launching the 32 bit version? and how i could make it launch a 64 bit version with the bat file like i have it?

Comment: Are you running the 64-bit cmd.exe or the 32-bit cmd.exe?  If you're running the 64-bit cmd.exe then a start of "powershell" should launch the 64-bit version of PowerShell.  The other option is to put your module also in `C:\Windows\SysWow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`.

Comment: its a bat file that is called by an eternal program so i think it might be calling the 32 bit version but i ma not sure also how can i get it to call the 64 bit . ie the batch file gets called and is opened with the 64 bit version automatically.ps thanks for your help so far

Comment: What happens if you put in this path to PowerShell in the bat file c:\windows\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe.  Note this path won't work if the bat is launched by a 32-bit process.

Comment: I cant put the path i have to call it exactly how you see it in my question or things wont work **START /min /wait powershell "C:\test.ps1" "%1"** .I mean the program calling it will fail i just not sure why cmd calls powershell 32 bit